# Set fixed column width for HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have this layout in html:

```html
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6">Name</th>
   <th colspan="4">Last Name</th>
    <th colspan="1">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:red;width:160px">first header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
     <td>header</td>
     <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
    <td><div><input value='cell'/></div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to set the first column width as `160px`. To do that i set the table style: `table-layout:fixed`, but this does not work, the first header still has the similar width as the rest of the columns.
 Question: How to get the expected behaviour?

Comment: Removing the 100% width on the table seems to fix the issue

Comment: @DarkBee removing the `width` value on the table also renders the `table-layout: fixed` property useless, as per [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

Comment: That's seem to be correct - The property `table-layout` will change to `auto` when no width (or auto) is specified. But I'm unsure if OP actually wants to use `fixed` then? The algorithm `fixed` makes use of the *first row* in order to calculate the table's layout so the adding width to a column on the second row will have no effect

Comment: @DarkBee, i updated the question, could you please take a look how i can get the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192960/css-style-for-first-td-in-a-tr

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove the `table-layout: fixed` style, and the table will remain at 100% width and the first columns width will be set to `160px`.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) is some useful documentation on how the `table-layout` property works.

If you want to continue using the `table-layout: fixed` property you can define a `<col>` with a width applied, and pass that as the scope for the first column as per my code snippet.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) on `<col>`

```html
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
  <colgroup>
    <col span="1" width="160px" />
  </colgroup>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6">Name</th>
   <th colspan="4">Last Name</th>
    <th colspan="1">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td scope="col" style="color: red;">first header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
     <td>header</td>
     <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
 <td>cell</td>
  <td>cell</td>
     <td>cell</td>
 <td>cell</td>
  <td>cell</td>
     <td>cell</td>
 <td>cell</td>
  <td>cell</td>
     <td>cell</td>
 <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i updated my question, i forgot to add inside each cell a div with an input. Could you help in this scenario? Note: is important that the fixed width should be set only on the table elements, not input or div.

Comment: The width isn't being set on the input elements - you can style these how you like. Input elements have a default size which is why the columns without an explicit width set appear bigger with an unstyled input element as their child.

Comment: @Asking I have updated my answer to include the use of the `table-layout: fixed` property. Let me know if you need any further clarification and I can update my answer!